# Is it possible to animate a div border?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` on some divs which add or remove the bottom border.  Is animating this possible?  Something like this:

`$("#left-title").addClass('active').show("slide", { direction: 'left', easing: 'easeInCirc' }, 1000);`

Thanks

Comment: Why is it that when i am typing my question, no previous questions that even remotely resembles my question appears, but after i submit it, i get relavant questions on the side bar?

Comment: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/simple-yet-amazing-css3-border-transition-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, use the [`transition` css3 property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp):

```css
div{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: .2em .5em .5em .5em;
    background: #eceded;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #bbb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
div:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0c0;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I am cooking dinner and will test after.  I will check as correct.

Comment: Whats with the pulsating effect?

Comment: ok thanks.  Might be a long shot but is there a way to do left to right or vice versa?  I am only using the bottom border and this would fit better with my other animations.